# Can Siri be invoked when opening iOS maps with directions?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, siri

From my iOS app I am invoking iOS maps with directions. Is it possible to also invoke Siri at the same time so voice directions can be given?

Here is the URL that I am currently using to invoke the maps:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr={start lat},{start long}&daddr={dest lat},{dest long}
```

Is there something I can pass along in that querystring to have Siri start giving directions when the maps app opens? I can't seem to find anything that says I can ([iOS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)) but my users swear this worked at some point.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Siri wont give directions till you are at the start point and the user presses "start".

so this will work:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=falkirk&dirflg=d&t=h
```

As it uses my current location as the start point, and falkirk is drivable to from my location. So setting the start and end point it wont work till you are at the start point.

e.g. this wont work for me as Im not in San Jose :(

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=San+Jose&daddr=San+Francisco&dirflg=r
```

Comment: in my case saddr is "supposed" to be my start point but maybe that is what the problem is. I will give your suggestion a try later today and report back. Thx.

Comment: No worries, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Might possibly be the GPS warming up too (not getting the current location accurately quick enough).

Comment: My preliminary testing shows that this solution works for me. As I suspected, when I pass in the position of the device to the map app via the saddr param siri does not kick in. If I leave that param out and let the map app determine my location siri works. Thx again.